# Grep matching string from one file to another

Tags: python

Can someone please let me know what is wrong with my below code. Its giving all the content of the file instead of giving matching content.

```
path="/backup/servers"
DATA="/SUPPORT/data.txt"
fd=os.listdir(path)
for i in fd[-15:]:
        if re.match("(.*)-MC(.*)",i):
                rslt=i.replace("-MC","")
                fh=open("wmc.txt",'w+')
                fh.write(rslt)
                fl=open(DATA,'r')
                for line1 in fl:
                        fh.seek(0,0)
                        for line2 in fh:
                                #if re.search(".*%s.*"%(line2),line1):
                                if re.search(line2,line1):
                                        print line1
                                        break
```

Comment: Without access to your data, this is very hard to troubleshoot or reproduce. If you have an empty line in `line2`, that would cause every `line1` to match.  Similarly, if `line2` contains a bare dot, every nonempty `line1` will match.  In both cases, you would probably actually want to trim any trailing line terminator before comparing, as the strings you *want* to match would generally not be found unless they occur at end of line.

Comment: See [mcve] for how to create a more meaningful question which we can troubleshoot and discuss without requiring access to your system and/or your local data.

Comment: Attempting to loop over `wmc.txt` like that seems inefficient at best and broken at worst.  You should probably try to read the records into memory instead, unless the file is positively huge.